# Angular WebComponent

Tags: angular, web-component

My question is about WebComponent Angular Standalone. I created one like this:

app.module.ts

```
      constructor(injector: Injector) {
        const comp = createCustomElement(AppComponent, { injector });
        customElements.define("mawc-bill", comp);
      }
```

app.component.ts

```
      @Input('secretPass')
      secretPass: string ="";
```

but when I try to insert my webComponent in a simple page HTML, my input doesn't work.

```
    <body>
        <mawc-bill  secretPass="secretPass"></mawc-bill>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I try this too:

```
    <mawc-bill  [secretPass]="secretPass"></mawc-bill>
    <mawc-bill  [secretPass]="'secretPass'"></mawc-bill>
    <mawc-bill  attribut-secretPass="'secretPass'"></mawc-bill>
```

Does someone have an idea ?

Comment: Do you work with angular-cli to create component and ... or work this manually?

Comment: Do you Declear created component on module?

Comment: Yes for your 2 questions :)

Comment: Is it possible to put your codes on jsFiddle and link it?